# C# XmlSerializer serialize multiple items with same name

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I need to create serializable (XML) object, which has to have three same values `AddressLine`. This is required from DHL, for integration.
From documentation:

```
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="CompanyName" type="CompanyNameValidator" />
<xsd:element name="AddressLine" type="AddressLine" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3"/>
<xsd:element name="City" type="City" minOccurs="0"/>
```

I need get XML which looks like this.

```
<Consignee>
    <CompanyName>Company</CompanyName>
    <AddressLine>address 1</AddressLine>
    <AddressLine>address 2</AddressLine>        
    <AddressLine>address 3</AddressLine>        
    <City>City</City>
</Consignee>
```

- I tried to create elements with different names and set new name with `[XmlElement("AddressLine")]`, but this is not working.

  ```
  public string CompanyName { get; set; }


  public string AddressLine { get; set; }

  [XmlElement("AddressLine")]
  public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

  [XmlElement("AddressLine")]
  public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

  public string City { get; set; }
  ```

Error message:

```
There was an error reflecting property 'AddressLine1'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
 The XML element 'AddressLine' from namespace '' is already present in the current scope. Use XML
 attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element.
```

- If I use array or list is not good or at least, I didn't succeed.
- My last idea is to serialize object with `AddressLine2` and `AddressLine3` to string and in string relapse values to `AddressLine`.

Is where a way create object, that after serialization look like in example?
Any suggestions?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: how about this solution, put ``AddressLine`` inside ``AddressLines``, the ``xml`` will be like:``<Consignee>
    <CompanyName>Company</CompanyName><AddressLines>
    <AddressLine>address 1</AddressLine>
    <AddressLine>address 2</AddressLine>        
    <AddressLine>address 3</AddressLine></AddressLines>        
    <City>City</City>
</Consignee>`` and use ``array``...

Comment: Make it an array : [XmlElement("AddressLine")]
public string[] AddressLine { get; set; }  You must have the XmlElement for it to work.

Comment: I tried this, but I am getting this:<Consignee>
    `<CompanyName>Company</CompanyName><AddressLines>
    <AddressLine>address 1</AddressLine>
    <AddressLine>address 2</AddressLine>        
    <AddressLine>address 3</AddressLine></AddressLines>   
    <City>City</City>
</Consignee>` and this ir not good. Server returning error.